# How to decrypt cocos2d luac type?

Tags: decryption, xor, lua

I am new with IDA and cocos2d. Since I have learned how to decrypt cocos2d Lua file, I found xxtea tool with Sign and Key and how to find Sign header in some game in Lua file.

But that method does not work with this game - *Six Path Legend：Revenge (size 869.7MB):*
[Link](https://m.apkpure.com/six-path-legend%EF%BC%9Arevenge/com.sixpathlegendr.gp)

The Luac file sign starts with `..C6E@..` header, but cannot find it in IDA.

How can we decrypt it?

- Lib file(libcocos2dlua.so, file size 9.45MB):
  [Download link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/r313b202yq4a2g3/libcocos2dlua.so/file)
- Luac file(main.luac, file size 3.63KB):
  [Download link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vle06tpawj8vxbf/main.luac/file)

Comment: did you find an answer? I'm also looking to solve this. (my discord Frost#9657)